# Pitch Accent Rule for Verb Stems?

Tags: pitch-accent

Are there known pitch accent rules or patterns for determining the pitch accent of verb stems? Things like:

> 見る   ⟶ 見
>
> 殺す   ⟶ 殺し
>
> 呼ぶ    ⟶   呼び
>
> 泳ぐ    ⟶   泳ぎ
>
> 書く    ⟶   書き
>
> 読む    ⟶   読み
>
> 死ぬ    ⟶   死に
>
> 走る    ⟶   走り
>
> 待つ    ⟶   待ち
>
> 使う    ⟶   使い
>
> 行く    ⟶   行き
>
> 来る    ⟶   来
>
> する   ⟶ し

I've been playing around with examples on [OJAD](https://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/phrasing/index), and while at first it seemed like Heiban verbs have Heiban stems and downstep verbs retain their downstep at the same mora position...eventually I found several counter-examples.

Comment: By *stem*, you mean the nouns corresponding to those verbs?

Comment: Yes. I was under the impression that masu-stems convert verbs into noun forms.

Comment: In case no one has told you yet, OJAD is wrong all the time, so you shouldn’t be trying to learn from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of those listed, I would recognize only the following as valid nouns in their own right (with 書き slightly off the borderline in my judgment).

> 殺す [ころす]{LHH} → 殺し [ころし□]{LHHH}
> 泳ぐ [およぐ]{LHL} → 泳ぎ [およぎ□]{LHHL}
> 読む [よむ]{HL} → 読み [よみ□]{LHL}
> 走る [はしる]{LHL} → 走り [はしり□]{LHHL}
> 待つ [まつ]{HL} → 待ち [まち□]{LHL}
> 使う [つかう]{LHH} → 使い [つかい□]{LHHH}
> 行く [いく]{LH} → 行き [いき□]{LHH}

From these limited samples, it seems that:

They all end high, and:

- stays high on the particle that follows (if it does), if the verb ends high (in its dictionary form)
- goes down on the particle that follows (if it does), if the verb ends low (in its dictionary form)

Those listed above are all Group-I verbs (or u-verbs). I checked some Group-II verbs (or ru-verbs) and found that many follow this pattern.

> 教える [おしえる]{LHHH} → 教え [おしえ□]{LHHH}
> 届ける [とどける]{LHHL} → 届け [とどけ□]{LHHL}
> 借りる [かりる]{LHH} → 借り [かり□]{LHH}

However, I also found a few exceptions (in both Group-I and II).

> 頑張る [がんばる]{LHHL} → 頑張り [がんばり□]{LHHHH}
> 着替える [きがえる]{LHHL} → 着替え [きがえ□]{LHHH}

[NHK](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/NHK%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E7%99%BA%E9%9F%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/prefix/%E3%81%8C%E3%82%93%E3%81%B0%E3%82%8A) lists [がんばり□]{LHHHL} and [がんばり□]{LHHLL}, too, but [がんばり□]{LHHHL}, which would conform to the pattern, seems the least common.

着替える is a compound verb if this matters. 替える has a different accent. ([きがえる]{LHHH} doesn’t sound too bad, either.)

> 替える [かえる]{LHH} → 替え [かえ□]{LHHH}

When these nouns are combined with other words, they may take on different accents.

> 平泳ぎ [ひらおよぎ□]{LHHLLL}
> 立ち読み [たちよみ□]{LHHHH}

Conclusion: There seems to be no definite rule, but the above might serve as a guideline.