# Verbs that cannot be taken as nouns in their い-stem (ます-stem)

Tags: verbs, nouns

I know that one of the ways of getting a noun from a verb is by taking the い-stem (or the ます-stem as some call it) of the verb. However I came across this:

> [image]

Taken from [here](https://maggiesensei.com/2017/06/26/verb-%E2%86%92noun-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%AF%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-%E3%80%9C%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-%E3%80%9C%E3%82%84%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-wa-shinai-mo-shinai-y/), where it says that there are some verbs that you can't do that with. I was wondering if there is some list of verbs that you can't make a noun out of their い-stem or are they too numerous to count (and therefore I will have to find them out through trial and error).

Thanks!

Comment: い-stem might not be the best term, since it would seem to only apply to verbs where the ます-stem ends with an い sound, but verbs like たべる (stem = たべ) or きめる (stem = きめ) would be excluded.

Comment: I agree and that is why I included also the term ます-stem

Comment: You would have to learn each word that **can** be used as a noun. It’s not much different from learners of English having to learn that “raise” can be used as a noun but for specific meanings, and “increase”, too, but with a different accent. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/96240/43676) about pitch accent.

Comment: It is good to know I'm not missing some secret list or pattern. I guess I'll learn it just like how I learned English - lots of exposure and trial and error, Thanks!